# Azure Blob Storage Container Stored Access Policy with ARM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to create a Stored Access Policy for Azure Blob Containers through an ARM template? If yes how?

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/establishing-a-stored-access-policy

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure - Using bicep to set storage container access policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164897/azure-using-bicep-to-set-storage-container-access-policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This api is not exposed through ARM >> you cannot use it in arm templates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create