# Azure - Using bicep to set storage container access policy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

Can Bicep be used to do what this Azure CLI script does?

```
az storage container policy create \
    --container-name $containerName \
    --name $policyName \
    --account-name $storageAccountName \
    --account-key $accountKey \
    --permissions $permissions \
    --start $policyStartTime \
    --expiry $policyEndTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It's not possible in ARM (see [Azure Blob Storage Container Stored Access Policy with ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708461/azure-blob-storage-container-stored-access-policy-with-arm)). Bicep is just a compiler that translates bicep code into ARM code that is used then to do the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bicep to attach access policies to a container. However, once your deployment is complete, you can use Azure PowerShell to attach the policies:

```
$ResourceGroupName = ""
$StorageAccountName = ""
$ContainerName = ""
$PolicyName = ""
$Permission = ""


$AzStorageContext = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName).Context
New-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy -Context $AzStorageContext -Container $ContainerName -Policy $PolicyName -Permission $Permission
```

Documentation:

- [Get-AzStorageAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageaccount)
- [New-AzStorageContainerStoredAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainerstoredaccesspolicy)